# Open an application on device connection

Tags: windows, macos, usb, itunes

When an iPhone/iPod/iPad is connected via usb port to a computer iTunes open up and begins to sync. The same goes for my wacom bamboo tablet. How do external devices make applications open on a computer? Do they use a special library?

Thanks

**P.S.**  My question extends to OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an application and put it in the auto startup or a service application:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx

make you application to register for device notification:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx

and write the code for OnDeviceChange to start whatever application you want if the event type is of the type interface arrival and it meets your additional requirements, like PID/VID...